# Rotate caret when accordion section is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have an accordion with four sections. Each section has a caret on it. I want each caret to rotate 180 degrees when its section is clicked. When an accordion section is clicked it will display a paragraph below it. The first paragraph is already displayed.

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
                <a href=""><div class="wow fadeInRight">Discovery <b class="caret"></b></div></a>
                <p class="wow fadeInRight">
                    Life is all about discovery. For me, this could be anything from traveling to a place
                    that I've never photographed, to learning something new about myself that helps me grow as a person.
                </p>
                <a href=""><div class="wow fadeInRight">Clarity <b class="caret"></b></div></a>
                <p>Creating high quality images is an important part of every photographer's process.
                    I emphasize clarity in my photography because it allows me to capture nature's finest details.
                </p>
                <a href=""><div class="wow fadeInRight">Authenticity <b class="caret"></b></div></a>
                <p>
                    These days it can be hard to find anything that is truly authentic. I focus on nature in my photography because I believe that authentic experiences
                    must be initiated by removing yourself from the distractions of everyday life and reconnecting with nature.
                </p>
                <a href=""><div class="wow fadeInRight">Mindfullness <b class="caret"></b></div></a>
                <p>Mindfullness is a mental state achieved by focusing one's awareness on the present moment, while calmly acknowledging and accepting one's feelings, thoughts, and sensations. This is commonly used as a therapeutic technique.
                 </p>
            </div><!--end accordion-->
```

JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//Hide all panels to start
var panels = $('.accordion > p').hide();

//Show first panel on load (optional)
panels.first().show();

//On click of panel title
$('.accordion > a > div').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    //slide up all other panels
    panels.slideUp();

    //slide down target panel
    $this.parent().next().slideDown();

    //flip closest caret 180 degrees
    $this.closest('.caret').css({'transform' : "rotate('180deg')"});

    return false;
});
```

});

The caret flip code is the 4th line from the bottom in my jquery

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: You've stated what you're after clearly, but you haven't stated what problem you're facing?

Comment: The line //flip closest caret 180 degrees
    $this.closest('.caret').css({'transform' : "rotate('180deg')"}); doesn't seem to work. Everything else works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues.

1. You haven't included the CSS, but I suspect you haven't set `.caret` to be a block type element, which is required for `transform` to work.
2. jQuery's `closest()` function checks the element's parents, whereas you're looking for a child, so you should use `find()` instead.
3. My approach would be to add an `active` class, either to the `caret` - in my example below, or on the header `div` itself (likely the later). This makes it easy to check in other sections of the code and avoids inline styling messing up your CSS.
4. If you want to go with your approach but using `find()` then remove the quotes around `180deg` (as I've done in the commented out code below).
5. Unrelated to this problem but `<b>` tags are considered old-fashioned so you may like to consider using `<strong>` instead.

Anyway, here's a reworked example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //Hide all panels to start
  var panels = $('.accordion > p').hide();

  //Show first panel on load (optional)
  panels.first().show();

  //On click of panel title
  $('.accordion > a > div').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $('.caret').removeClass("active");

    //slide up all other panels
    panels.slideUp();

    //slide down target panel
    $this.parent().next().slideDown();
   
    $this.find('.caret').addClass("active");
     
/*  //flip closest caret 180 degrees
    $this.find('.caret').css({
      'transform': "rotate(180deg)"
    });
*/
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.caret {
   display: inline-block;
}

.caret:after {
  content: ">";
   display: inline-block;
}

.caret.active {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <a href="">
    <div class="wow fadeInRight">Discovery <strong class="caret active"></strong></div>
  </a>
  <p class="wow fadeInRight">
    Life is all about discovery. For me, this could be anything from traveling to a place that I've never photographed, to learning something new about myself that helps me grow as a person.
  </p>
  <a href="">
    <div class="wow fadeInRight">Clarity <strong class="caret"></strong></div>
  </a>
  <p>Creating high quality images is an important part of every photographer's process. I emphasize clarity in my photography because it allows me to capture nature's finest details.
  </p>
  <a href="">
    <div class="wow fadeInRight">Authenticity <strong class="caret"></strong></div>
  </a>
  <p>
    These days it can be hard to find anything that is truly authentic. I focus on nature in my photography because I believe that authentic experiences must be initiated by removing yourself from the distractions of everyday life and reconnecting with nature.
  </p>
  <a href="">
    <div class="wow fadeInRight">Mindfullness <strong class="caret"></strong></div>
  </a>
  <p>Mindfullness is a mental state achieved by focusing one's awareness on the present moment, while calmly acknowledging and accepting one's feelings, thoughts, and sensations. This is commonly used as a therapeutic technique.
  </p>
</div>
<!--end accordion-->
```